# Changing the "countryList" dropdown default in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

The PhoneFactor country code dropdown has the USA on top.

The list is:

```
StringId="countryList">{"DEFAULT":"Country/Region","AF":"Afghanistan ...
```

It looks as if "DEFAULT" is set to the USA somewhere but I don't see any references to this.

I want the default to be e.g. "NZ".

I can do this by reordering the elements but it would be much simpler if I could simply change the default.

Is there a mapping somewhere for this?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before, the way I worked around it was to make sure that the default I wanted was the first one on the list. So in your case

```
StringId="countryList">{"NZ":"New Zealand","AF":"Afghanistan ...
```

Comment: I used the same method of reordering the countries.